# How to Access Client_id of Calling Client in Identity Server 4 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 for authentication for both a website and WPF application. On the website, I want users to have the ability to check a Remember Me box when signing in, but I don't want that for the WPF application. I have the logic to disable that checkbox on the front end, but am having trouble in my controller. I have this function

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    LoginViewModel _vm;
    _vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);
    //if(Client_id == "wpf") <- this is what I need help with
    //{
    //    _vm.AllowRememberMe = false;
    //}
    return View(_vm);  
}
```

This controller contains

```
private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService mInteraction;
private readonly IClientStore mClientStore;
private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider mSchemeProvider;
private readonly IEventService mEvents;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the client id from the `AuthorizationRequest` returned from the `IIdentityServerInteractionService` as follows using your code snipet:

```
var context = await mInteraction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
_vm.AllowedRememberMe = context.ClientId != "wpf";
```

However, you would be better off placing this logic in your `BuildLoginViewModelAsync` method where the view model is constructed rather than setting the property after construction.

Comment: This works great. I did put it in my BuildLoginViewModelAsync, i just didn't want to clutter up my question. Also, i have to access it through context.Client.ClientId, but otherwise this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the client_id is directly available from any IS4 constructs in the Login method.  However, depending on your OIDC flow, it's likely that your client_id was passed as part of the "returnUrl" parameter.  Look at your return URL and see if it's there.

For example, I have a spa website connecting to IS4 that shows a returnURL of:

```
https://localhost:8080/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DspaClient%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps...(long url continues)
```

You can see that it contains the "client_id" parameter with a value of "spaClient".  Simply parse the returnUrl using your code of choice (e.g. RegEx) and extract the client_id from there.  I don't have any WPF experience, so it may behave differently and not pass this parameter.